Change reference text for references without a date
I am using the natbib citation management package with \bibliographystyle{agsm}. When citing a source without a year field, 'n.d.' will be generated, e.g.: "(Doe et al., n.d.)".
Is it possible to change 'n.d.' to 'o.D' since im writing in German?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Aside: Since you say you're writing in German, I will assume you're also executing \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}. In addition, to get the conjunction between authors to say "und" rather than "and" (the default), be sure to run \providecommand{\harvardand}{und} after loading the natbib package.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) resp. minimal working example with bbliography (MWEB) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

I suggest you proceed as follows:

Find the file agsm.bst in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, agsm-oD.bst. (Don't edit an unmodified/unrenamed file out of your TeX distribution directly.)

Open the file agsm-oD.bst in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.

In the file agsm-oD.bst, find the function called reverse.pass. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 1282.)

Inside the reverse.pass function, locate the following line:
 { "n.d." extra.label emphasize * 'list.year := }

Change it -- you guessed correctly -- to
 { "o.D." extra.label emphasize * 'list.year := }


Save the file agsm-oD.bst either in the directory that contains your main tex file(s) or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. (If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, I suggest you choose the first option...)

In the main tex file, change the instruction \bibliographystyle{agsm} to \bibliographystyle{agsm-oD}.

Perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to propagate the effects of the change to the bibliography style file.


Happy BibTeXing!

Worked perfectly. Thank you.
